# How to do an AJAX post to an Umbraco Web Api

Tags: umbraco8

I am using Umbraco 8.17 and I am trying to do an ajax post to an umbraco web api. I know from the Umbraco documentation that I need to make a new controller that extends UmbracoApiController. I also know that when I want to call a method in this controller I need to put "/Umbraco/Api/" at the head of the url. So if my controller is in the base folder of controllers and my controller is named myController and the method I want to call on that controller is MyMethod, the url would be something like "https://localhost:44305/Umbraco/Api/myController/MyMethod" if I were to be running the code from debug in Visual Studio.

Now from a partial view I want to trigger a javascript function that does a AJAX call to that method "assume the method takes no parameters:. My AJAX call in my partial view (cshtml) file would look like this.

```
 function MYAJAXCAll() {
        alert("In the function call");
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Umbraco/Api/myController /MyMethod",
                success: function (response) {
                    alert(response);
                }
            });
        }
```

Note that at this point I am just trying to get the method call to work. once I have that done I can go back and make it actually do something meaningful.

The problem is that the ajax call is not working. It doesn't even seam to be firing. I will get the alert but nothing else. note that I do have a breakpoint in the method that should be catching if the method is called and that is not happening.

Comment: Also note that I have tested the function with Postman and it works

Comment: please highligh some code

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the simple web api call to work using jQuery.

Here is the code that I used to make it work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.getJSON("/Umbraco/Api/myController/MyMethod")
                .done(function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                });
        });
```